# Is there a better (more pythonic) way to write file content to list?

Tags: python, file-io

I am currently using the following statement to write each line of a file to a list

```
try:
  list = []
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
      list.append(l)
except:
  ...
```

while it works just fine, I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this?

**EDIT:**
With the suggested updates

```
try:
  my_list = []
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()
except IOError:
  ...
```

Comment: `f.readlines()` is already a list.

Comment: You should not have a `try:... except:...` statement without choosing what Exceptions to catch, it is generally considered very bad practice and can cause you a lot of trouble.

Comment: And don't  use `list` as a variable name, otherwise `list(f)` suggested in the answers won't work for you.

Comment: ok my lessons learned here: don't simplify your code if you are looking for improvement :-) 
I am completely aware of exceptions and list as variable and was looking for improvement of the readlines statement. Thanks anyway for pointing it out, so others won't adapt those bad practices. I guess, that's where the downvotes are coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is in Python's documentation of [Methods of File Objects section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) itself,

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`.

If you are going to process the file, line-by-line, then just iterate the file object, like this

```
for line in f:
    # Process line
```

This will be highly memory efficient, as all the lines are not read at a time and stored in memory.

Comment: sometimes life is simple. thanks! :-) I'll accept it as soon as SO let me

Comment: what's your ````list(f)```` usage? for me it returns the whole file as the one list element.

Comment: @nettux443: You do have line breaks in the file, right? And you didn't accidentally stick an extra pair of brackets somewhere, making `f` already a list?

Comment: my bad it does work. I ran it on some html that I thought had line breaks.. apparently not.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do:

```
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lst = f.readlines()
except IOError:
    print("File doesn't exist")
```

`f.readlines()` already returns a list of all the lines in the file.

or ***even*** more simply:

```
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lst = list(f)
except IOError:
    print("File doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Op here: wasn't me. Answer is just fine

Comment: The post has been edited since you asked why the downvotes, and while I didn't vote on your post, the original version was calling list() on a list object (which you noticed as you have added "f.readlines() already returns a list of all the lines in the file.").

Comment: @Dr.Elch It returns as a list for me. I've checked with ````type(f.readlines()) => <type 'list'>````, ````isinstance(f.readlines(), types.GeneratorType) => False```` and ````isinstance(f.readlines(), types.ListType) => True````